# Discord on_message is doing absolutely nothing

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to figure out the Discord Python API. Have followed multiple tutorials and read practically the whole documentation.
From what I see in the code, I am doing it the same as everyone not having my issue.

- I have turned on all permissions for the "bot" in discord
- Set admin permissions in the "OAuth2" section.
- The python program successfully runs the on_ready function and prints its message to terminal.
- Then the program just idles until I force close.
- I'm sending the messages in discord on my server after I run the python program.

Is there a setup step on the site I am missing or is it my code? Any help is greatly appreciated. **(If unclear I am simply trying to print all of the message content to terminal whenever a new message is sent in the discord server.)**

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)

client.run('BOT TOKEN') # I HAVE THE ACTUAL BOT TOKEN IN MY CODE
```

**Problem has been solved**

Turns out the method I used to add the bot to server was incorrect.
I went wrong by not using the 'URL Generator' method to invite the bot.

URL Generator --> Select 'bot' --> Select 'admin' --> Copy URL --> Visit URL --> Select server

Comment: Are you sending the messages on a channel where the bot can see? Have you added the bot to your server?

Comment: I cant tell the error but I can say that your error is not inside your code. It's running perfectly fine for me. So there must be something wrong with your Bot, your permissions or your discord.py

Answer (score 0):

did you enable message content intents in the dev portal?

Comment: I have enabled message content intent and all other permissions on the bot page.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the process_commands() to the event to make it work:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
    await client.process_commands(message)
client.run('BOT TOKEN') # I HAVE THE ACTUAL BOT TOKEN IN MY CODE
```

Comment: No success with this. Program still does the same thing. No new errors, just blank terminal until I force close.